# how to center logo on AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

how to center logo on AppBarLayout

i want add logo @drawable/logo on center appbarlayout and add menu icon ( rtl is true ) like screenshot

current layout screenshot:

[image: current screenshot]

i want this layout, screenshot:

[image: i want this, screenshot]

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static MainActivity instance;
    private HomeFragment homeFragment;
    private ProfilesFragment profilesFragment;
    private CategoriesFragment categoriesFragment;
    private TabLayout allTabs;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private int[] tabIcons = {
            R.drawable.home,
            R.drawable.profiles,
            R.drawable.categories
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        instance = this;
        getAllWidgets();
        bindWidgetsWithAnEvent();
        setupTabLayout();

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        setupTabIcons();

        // screen turn on ever
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);


        // RTL Toolbar
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
        }
    }

    private void setupTabIcons() {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(tabIcons[0]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(tabIcons[1]);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(tabIcons[2]);
    }

    public static MainActivity getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    private void getAllWidgets() {
        allTabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    }

    private void setupTabLayout() {
        homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        profilesFragment = new ProfilesFragment();
        categoriesFragment = new CategoriesFragment();
        allTabs.addTab(allTabs.newTab().setText("خانه"), true);
        allTabs.addTab(allTabs.newTab().setText("شخصیت\u200Cها"));
        allTabs.addTab(allTabs.newTab().setText("دسته\u200Cبندی\u200Cها"));
    }

    private void bindWidgetsWithAnEvent() {
        allTabs.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                setCurrentTabFragment(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            }
        });
    }

    private void setCurrentTabFragment(int tabPosition) {
        switch (tabPosition) {
            case 0:
                replaceFragment(homeFragment);
                break;
            case 1:
                replaceFragment(profilesFragment);
                break;
            case 2:
                replaceFragment(categoriesFragment);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment);
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        ft.commit();
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    /**
     * Check Connectivity of network.
     */
    public static class NetworkUtil {
        public static int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
        public static int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
        public static int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;
        public static final int NETWORK_STATUS_NOT_CONNECTED = 0, NETWORK_STAUS_WIFI = 1, NETWORK_STATUS_MOBILE = 2;

        public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (null != activeNetwork) {
                if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
                    return TYPE_WIFI;

                if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
                    return TYPE_MOBILE;
            }
            return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
        }

        public static int getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) {
            int conn = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
            int status = 0;
            if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI) {
                status = NETWORK_STAUS_WIFI;
            } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                status = NETWORK_STATUS_MOBILE;
            } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
                status = NETWORK_STATUS_NOT_CONNECTED;
            }
            return status;
        }

        public static boolean isOnline(Context context) {
            try {
                if (context == null)
                    return false;

                ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

                if (cm != null) {
                    if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null) {
                        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1.** Add a `RelativeLayout` as a direct child of `AppBarLayout`.

**2.** Put `Toolbar` and `ImageView` inside `RelativeLayout`.

**3.** Add attribute `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to `imageView` to show at `center` of `Toolbar`.

**Here is the working code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mainCoordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_logo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <!-- Your Content here -->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**In your activity, add below lines:**

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(""); // hide title
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Comment: thanks very much. how to add menu button, this Add Back button

Comment: Create a `menu.xml` in your `res/menu` folder and in your activity ovverride `onCreateOptionsMenu()` to add menu on this activity `Toolbar`. Here is an complete tutorial: http://alvinalexander.com/android/how-to-create-options-menu-item-actionbar-respond-tap-click

Comment: @user8215914 Thanks for accepting my answer. If my answer seems useful, I hope you will give an up-vote. Thank you~

Comment: thanks, it works great. Btw you don't need: app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp" android:layout_centerInParent="true"

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
            app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_logo"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```